# VBA Creating hyperlink to another dynamic workbook

Tags: vba, excel, hyperlink

I am struggling to find a solution for my problem:

I have a list of items on one workbook and a macro that creates a sheet for each item on different spreadsheets.

Each Code in Column A has the type of product as the first Letter and each product type gets its own workbook.

All codes work fine, except the Hyperlink.

I need to hyperlink each code to the sheet when it is created.

When run, it hyperlinks my cells to "C:\Users\Reception\Documents\Shared\Item Master Data\Stock\" not opening my sheet.

What am I missing? My FULL code is as follows.

```
Sub StockSheets()

        Sheets("Component List").Select
          Range("A2").Select 'Start with first item code'

    Do Until ActiveCell = " "

          GoTo Openwb 'check if wbStock is already open'

NewType: 'if wbStock is not open'

          Dim StType As String, wbStock As Workbook, wsTEMP As Worksheet

                If Left(ActiveCell, 1) = "B" Then
                    StType = "Bulk Stock.xlsx"

                Else
                    If Left(ActiveCell, 1) = "F" Then
                        StType = "Finished Goods Stock.xlsx"

                        Else
                            If Left(ActiveCell, 1) = "P" Then
                                StType = "Packaging Stock.xlsx"

                                Else
                                    If Left(ActiveCell, 1) = "R" Then
                                        StType = "Raw Mat Stock.xlsx"
                                    End If
                            End If
                    End If
            End If

            Set wbStock = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\Reception\Documents\Shared\Item Master Data\Stock\" & StType)

Resume Cont1 'skip Openwb part'

Openwb:

On Error GoTo NewType 'Open wbStock'

        wbStock.Activate

Cont1:

            Set wsTEMP = Sheets("Stock Template")

        wsTEMP.Copy After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count) 'Copies the Stock template to a new sheet'

        Sheets(Sheets.Count).Activate

        Application.Workbooks("Item Master Data.xlsm").Activate
            Worksheets("Component List").Select

On Error GoTo Exist 'if Sheetname exists'

        wbStock.Worksheets("Stock Template (2)").Name = ActiveCell.Value 'Name the new sheet as per the active cell on Component List'

        wbStock.Activate

        Range("A1:B1").Copy
            Range("A1:B1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues 'Paste the formulas as values to speed up computer'

        Range("A:J").Select
        Columns.AutoFit 'neaten the sheet'

        ThisWorkbook.Activate 'Go back to Item Master Data workbook with Component list'

        Dim FPath As String
            FPath = "C:\Users\Reception\Documents\Shared\Item Master Data\Stock\" & StType

        Sheets("Component List").Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=Excel.Selection, _
            Address:="C:\Users\Reception\Documents\Shared\Item Master Data\Stock\" & StType & "#" & ActiveCell.Value & "!A1" 'Hyperlink item code to newly created sheet on wbStock'

Cont2:

        If Left(ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0), 1) = Left(ActiveCell, 1) Then
Resume Cont3 'Check if next stType is the same as the Active Cell'

            Else
                wbStock.Close True 'Save and close wbStock'
        End If

Cont3:

        ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select 'Select next item'

    Loop

Exist: 'If the sheet already exists'

            Sheets("Componet List").Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=Selection, _
            Address:=wbStock.Worksheets(ActiveCell).Range("A1")

            Application.DisplayAlerts = False
                Worksheets("Stock Template (2)").Delete
            Application.DisplayAlerts = True 'Delete the newly created sheet before looping with the next item'

Resume Cont2 

        ActiveSheet.Cells.Font.Size = 10 'Neaten Sheet'

            Range("A1").Select
            Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
            Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select

        With Selection.Borders
            .LineStyle = xlContinuous
            .Color = 0
            .Weight = xlThin
        End With

        With Columns("A:ZZ").AutoFit
            Range("A1").Select
        End With

End Sub
```

Comment: What exactly is the issue? you're adding hyperlinks to the cells. If your intention was to open the workbook then do workbooks.open(fpath). *Edit*: If your intention is to custom hyperlink each cell in a range then post the entire loop that i'm assuming you're using.

Comment: if it links only to C:\Users\Reception\Documents\Shared\Item Master Data\Stock\ then it sounds like the criteria that set the variable StType are not being met so the variable is empty "".  your code is checking against the ActiveCell so you need to ensure that the cell you have selected when you run the macro contains the Code you are using to set the hyperlink.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `Select Case` to ensure that your criteria are a match.

Adding a `SubAddress` in the hyperlink should allow you to arrive on the right sheet.
If there is spaces in some name, you'll have to add `'` around the sheet name.

And you should avoid working with `ActiveCell` or `Select` they are not efficient to say the least.

```
Dim StType As String, FPath As String
Select Case Left(ActiveCell, 1)
    Case Is = "B"
        StType = "Bulk Stock.xlsx"
    Case Is = "F"
        StType = "Finished Goods Stock.xlsx"
    Case Is = "P"
        StType = "Packaging Stock.xlsx"
    Case Is = "R"
        StType = "Raw Mat Stock.xlsx"
    Case Else
        MsgBox "Case not handled for type : " & Left(ActiveCell, 1), _
                vbOKOnly + vbInformation
        Exit Sub
End Select

FPath = "C:\Users\Reception\Documents\Shared\Item Master Data\Stock\" & StType

Sheets("Component List").Hyperlinks.Add _
    Anchor:=ActiveCell, _
    Address:=FPath, _
    SubAddress:=ActiveCell.Value & "!A1"
```

Comment: Thanks. I have edited my OP with my full code. It runs through each code individually and does a few things per code before moving to the next. As Codes are added to the list (Will be random), I want my code to only add the new codes.

Comment: @Almie : Ok, Have you tested what I proposed for the hyperlink? Does it work? Do you have a list of all treated codes or something like that?

Comment: Struggled to get it right, but finally got it! Thanks #R3uK.

Comment: Dim FPath As String
                FPath = "C:\Users\Reception\Documents\Shared\Item Master Data\Stock\" & StType

            Sheets("Component List").Hyperlinks.Add     Anchor:=Excel.Selection, _
                Address:=FPath, _
                SubAddress:=ActiveCell.Value & "!A1" 'Hyperlink item code to newly created sheet on wbStock'

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use a formula to create the hyperlinks instead of a macro as from your code it looks like you're running the macro on one call at a time.

This example assumes that your code is in column A.  put the formula in the first row of another column and then autofill down to create hyperlinks of all the codes.  i've only included the first couple of files so that it's not too complicated to follow but you just need to add the other nested ifs.

```
=IF(LEFT(A1,1)="B",HYPERLINK("C:\Users\Reception\Documents\Shared\Item Master Data\Stock\Bulk Stock.xlsx","Bulk Stock.xlsx"),IF(LEFT(A1,1)="F",HYPERLINK("C:\Users\Reception\Documents\Shared\Item Master Data\Stock\Finished Goods Stock.xlsx","Finished Goods Stock.xlsx"),""))
```

Here's the whole formula in all it's nested glory.

```
=IF(LEFT(A1,1)="B",HYPERLINK("C:\Users\Reception\Documents\Shared\Item Master Data\Stock\Bulk Stock.xlsx","Bulk Stock.xlsx"),IF(LEFT(A1,1)="B",HYPERLINK("C:\Users\Reception\Documents\Shared\Item Master Data\Stock\Bulk Stock.xlsx","Bulk Stock.xlsx"),IF(LEFT(A1,1)="P",HYPERLINK("C:\Users\Reception\Documents\Shared\Item Master Data\Stock\Packaging Stock.xlsx","Packaging Stock.xlsx"),IF(LEFT(A1,1)="R",HYPERLINK("C:\Users\Reception\Documents\Shared\Item Master Data\Stock\Raw Mat Stock.xlsx","Raw Mat Stock.xlsx"),""))))
```

Comment: I want to avoid formulas, as this slows down my computer too much.